# Grammar to parse a chess move using PEG

Tags: parsing, peg

What is the correct grammar to parse a move in SAN format using [PEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)?

The solution I come up is

```
MOVE <- [NBRQK]? [a-h]? [1-8]? [-x]? [a-h] [1-8] [NBRQ]?
```

However, this seems wrong as it doesn't parse Nh4 because h matches the first optional file [a-h]? and the parser doesn't backtrack.

Other moves that should be correctly parsed are:
a4, a3a4, xa4, a8Q, xa8Q, Nh4, Nxh4, Ngxh4, Ng3h4,Ngh4, N3h4, Ng3-h4, Ng3xh4, but (optionally) not -a4, N-h4.

Answer (score -2):

I've built algebraic notation parsers before.

Frankly, the grammar is pretty simple (as  you show, didn't check details).

More importantly, I don't recall any need to backtrack, which is the point of using PEG.   So you don't need a mechanism this complex.

In fact, "parsing" this is so simple that building a real parser seems like overkill; you can build an FSA to recognize it without much trouble.

Comment: I have an EPD parser. Move parsing is just one small part of it.

Comment: You may have other troubles, but your question related only to parsing moves.

Comment: The question is related to move parsing using *PEG*. I have a simpler grammar for move parsing implemented manually. PEG is important because the rest of my grammars are in PEG and I need proper integration.

Comment: Your problem is your grammar is too simple.   It hasn't anything to do with PEG or backtracking.   I'm not going to write your grammar for you.